# Open Ubuntu Server in Windows Explorer

Tags: server, windows, file-sharing

I have a ubuntu server with some music on it. I would like my windows 7 and windows 8 laptops to access this music through windows explorer. If I can view them on windows explorer, my music programs can probably find and play the music.

Right now, I have samba installed on my ubuntu server. I went through the config file and changed everything, so all users can access files. (I think... I know I changed the setting when I was installing my printer, but I do not know if there are any additional changes I need).

On the Windows side, when I open windows explorer, I see Network Infrastructure: Molecule. (Molecule is the name of my ubuntu server) If I click on it, it takes me to a webpage (IP address: 192.168.1.1) and asks me for a password. This obviously does not work since my ubuntu server ip address is actually: 192.168.1.119 .

If you have any tips to make my ubuntu server appear in windows explorer with the correct ip address, and super accessible, I am all ears.

smd.conf ==

```
[global]
guest account = happy
netbios name = Carbon
security = share
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
encrypt passwords = true
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user

[public]
guest ok = yes
guest only = yes
path = /
read only = no

[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = yes
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes

[hydrogen]
comment = share hydrogen files
path = /mnt/hydrogen
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = yes
force user = root
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

Comment: You should see your server at least twice, the infrastructure icon that opens a Web page is from something that uses upnp, maybe a media server. You should see a second icon in Explorer from the samba service.

Comment: If your hydrogen share already works you only need to duplicate the block and change the name and the path.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing two lines under the hydrogen part of my file.

```
public = yes
force group = root
```

I also changed to static IP.

After that, my ubuntu computer showed up under networks on microsoft.